# calculate reflect back angle after collision

Tags: javascript

i was making a game. i dont want the players to move out of the borders. i wrote a little for this. i also want the players to reflect back or boost back when collided with the borders with a boost. here's what i tried. it doesn't work for reflecting back.

```
Blob.prototype.borderCheck = function() {
    var xStart = 0;
    var xEnd = this.server.config.width;
    var yStart = 0;
    var yEnd = this.server.config.width;

    if (this.isBoosting() && this.x <= xStart) {
        this.setBoost(-this.getBoostAngle());
    }
    if (this.isBoosting() && this.x >= xEnd) {
        this.setBoost(-this.getBoostAngle());
    }
    if (this.isBoosting() && this.y <= yStart) {
        this.setBoost(-this.getBoostAngle());
    }
    if (this.isBoosting() && this.y >= yEnd) {
        this.setBoost(-this.getBoostAngle());
    }

    this.x = Math.min(xEnd, Math.max(this.x, xStart));
    this.y = Math.min(yEnd, Math.max(this.y, yStart));
};
```

it should be more like this one: https://cs.stanford.edu/people/eroberts/courses/soco/projects/1997-98/ray-tracing/images/reflection.gif

Comment: "i doesn't work" is vague, and what is `this.boosting`?

Comment: sorry i forgot the this keyword. but still it doesnt work

Comment: What doesn't work? What does your app do? What do you want it to do differently?

Comment: Yeah, there's not enough to go on in your code, I fear.  What I can tell you is that it appears the reflection model you are choosing is one in which you draw an imaginary line at the collision point, perpendicular to the impacted surface.  Whatever the angle is that is formed between your trajectory towards the surface and the imaginary line, you want to reflect at that same angle on the other side of the perpendicular line.

Comment: Also provide a [mcve]. The code you show here has several undefined variables and methods.

Answer (score 0):

When I wrote a similar program in the past, I stored the velocity vector as x and y components. Then collision with vertical or horizontal walls is as simple as negating the correct component.

Comment: what? can u please explain

Comment: whole part. i didnt get anything

Comment: @badboy24 I suggest that you learn the physics of motion. Since you are making a game with moving objects, understanding the terminology, such as velocity, acceleration, and vectors is incredibly important.